# Rank for JPEG quality

Tags: php, jpeg

I have to check few JPEG files for quality level and give to every file corresponding quality mark. Then I must be able to choose better image by this mark.

How to decide about visual image quality?

I'm dealing with photographs. Image dimensions and even compression ratio cannot indicate 
visual quality of of the image. For example, if you enlarge the image and save it with bigger quality the visual quality will be reduced...

The code is in PHP.

Any advises will be very thankful!

Comment: You could make a function that checks the image size depending on the dimensions - you can come up with the default values depending on how good the image quality will be.  For example, an image that's 1200px by 800px must be higher than 1.5MB, or if you're comparing images, you choose the one that has the highest size-to-dimensions ratio

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the original image then SSIM is one of the better methods to do this. It'd be pretty slow to do in pure PHP, but if you can execute shell commands, check [DSSIM tool](https://github.com/pornel/dssim) (you'll need to adapt it to load JPEGs instead of PNGs).

ImageMagick has `compare` command that can return Mean Square Error/PSNR of the image (compared to original), but these measurements only check per-pixel differences, so they are a poor way measure distortion caused by blockyness and ringing of JPEG compression.